# Not getting output for oozie job

Tags: apache, hadoop, oozie, hadoop2

I am trying to run an oozie job for Word Count MapReduce job but getting a blank **output** file. Text file resides in '/word' directory of HDFS and jar file in '/map-reduce/lib'. I am running below command to execute oozie job:

**oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config map-reduce/job.properties -run**

```
**My workflow.xml:**

<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="map-reduce-wf">
    <start to="mr-node"/>
    <action name="mr-node">
    <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="{nameNode}/word_dir"></delete>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>default</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>MyMap</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>MyReduce</value>
                </property>
        <property>
               <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
             </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/word</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/word_dir</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
    </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

**and job.properties:**

```
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/map-reduce
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you check the logs of map-reduce job, which is running your word count program?

Comment: That is fine. Oozie launches a mapper for launching the actual word count map reduce job. Did you check those logs. You can check the oozie logs as well as a first step of debugging.

Comment: While running oozie job just got a job ID. This one : job: 0000000-160424011152234-oozie-oozi-W

Got this from var/log/oozie:
2016-04-23 11:58:09,700  INFO PauseTransitService:520 - SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] Acquired lock for [org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTransitService]
2016-04-23 11:59:01,466    [org.apache.oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService]
2016-04-23 11:59:08,563  INFO StatusTransitRunnable:520 - SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] Acquired lock for

Comment: This does not seems relevant. Please add logs to the post only. It is not easy to read logs in comment section.

Comment: I am using new MR API, that's why was facing the issue. Got the solution. Replaced mapred.mapper.class and mapred.reducer.class with mapreduce.map.class and mapreduce.reduce.class. Moreover, I added two more properties: mapred.mapper.new-api and mapred.reducer.new-api and set value true for both of the properties. Thanks for your help